# Error for angles in radians

Tags: siunitx

When I want to insert the value of an angle equal to pi radian in my file with the command `\qty{\pi}{\radian}` I get an error "Package siunitx Erro : Invalid number '\pi'

how to make appear in this case the value of pi radian using the package?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to register `\pi` as a 'digit'

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-digits = 0123456789\pi}
\begin{document}
\qty{\pi}{\radian}
\end{document}
```

or turn off the parser

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\qty[parse-numbers = false]{\pi}{\radian}
\end{document}
```